# How do I check for duplicates in a large txt file in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I just need a handy little tool that will check for duplicate lines in a text file, and it will delete those duplicates. So if the file said:

```
A
B
C
D
A
E
```

it will turn into:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

Nice and simple. But the text file will be large and full of long file locations, and I need to ensure that there is no more then ONE of any file. it does not matter which of the duplicates is deleted, as long as only one remains. So I would be okay with something like:

```
B
C
D
A
E
```

Here's all that I have so far:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set v=0
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("SomeArray.txt") do (
set /a var+=1
set var!v!=%%a
)
pause
```

I have no idea where to begin on making the loop to test all the possible duplicates.

Comment: I have the code to read the file and set all lines into variables titled var1, var2, var3 ect.

Answer (score 1):

create a cmd file uniqeline.cmd with this content:

```
@echo off
set prev=
for /f %%a in ('sort %1') do call :oneline %%a
goto :eof

:oneline
if NOT !%1!==!%prev%! echo %1
set prev=%1
goto :eof
```

Call from the commandline:

```
uniqeline yourfilewithfilesnames.lst
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code to store the lines in an "array" is broken. You should be incrementing `v` instead of `var`.

The code to check for duplicates is simple, but slow. Simply loop through the existing values to see if it matches the current line. Only echo and store the current line if no match was found. The higher the number of unique lines, the slower it gets.

The script below expects the name of the file as the 1st and only parameter

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set n=0
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in (%1) do (
  set "skip="
  for /l %%N in (1 1 !n!) do if "%%A"=="!var%%N!" set skip=1
  if not defined skip (
    echo %%A
    set /a n+=1
    set "var!n!=%%A"
  )
)
```

The above will fail if a line begins with `;` because the default FOR /F EOL option will skip lines that begin with `;`. That can be fixed with some awkward syntax that sets both EOL and DELIMS to nothing: `usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^=`

The above will also fail if any line contains `!` because delayed expansion will corrupt the value of the line when the FOR /F variable is expanded. That can be fixed by carefully enabling and disabling delayed expansion as needed.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set n=0
for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (%1) do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  set "skip="
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /l %%N in (1 1 !n!) do if "!ln!"=="!var%%N!" set skip=1
  if defined skip (endlocal) else (
    echo !ln!
    set /a n+=1
    for %%N in (!n!) do (
      endlocal
      set "var%%N=%%A"
      set "n=%%N"
    )
  )
)
```

But there are much faster and simpler solutions.

The fastest and simplest possible pure batch solution is to incorporate the line content into the name of a variable. To check for duplicates, simply check if the variable is already defined.

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: clear existing _ variables
for /f "eol== delims==" %%V in ('set _ 2^>nul') do set "%%V="

:: read and echo file, throw away duplicates (case insensitive)
:: does not work if line contains =
for /f usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in (%1) do (
  if not defined _%%A (
    echo %%A
    set "_%%A=1"
  )
)
```

There are 2 major limitations with the above solution.

- The duplicate comparison is case insensitive because variable names are case insensitive.
- The solution will not properly detect duplicates containing `=` because `=` cannot be included in a variable name.

I believe rene's solution using SORT is the best generally applicable approach, although rene's code has the following shortcomings

- The use of CALL significantly slows performance (noticeable with large files)
- Lines beginning with `;` are skipped
- Special characters like `&` `|` `<` `>` `^` cause problems
- The script assumes there is only one space delimited token

The shortcomings are easily fixed:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "old="
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ('sort %1') do (
  set "new=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  if "!new!" equ "!old!" (endlocal) else (
    echo !new!
    endlocal
    set "old=%%A"
  )
)
```

All batch solutions are limited to a maximum line length of ~8191 characters.

Also, all solutions above will strip empty lines.